# strange wc behavior in shell

Tags: shell

this is shell in MAC,
why is word count (wc) showing wrong character count?

```
sh-3.2# /Users/orly/Desktop/random.password.py 1
5
sh-3.2# /Users/orly/Desktop/random.password.py 1 | wc -m
       2
sh-3.2#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a newline character in your file.  That would explain a char count of 2.

ADDENDUM: Try this:

```
hexdump -C
```

on the "file".

ADDENDUM 2:

In more detail:

```
$ echo "dog" | wc -m
   4
$ echo "dog" | hexdump -C
00000000  64 6f 67 0a                                       |dog.|
00000004
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

The character count is correct:

```
$ echo 5 | od -c
0000000   5  \n
0000002
$ echo 5 | wc -m
2
```

There are two characters being output, a '5' and a '\n'.

---

As opposed to:

```
$ echo -n 5 | od -c
0000000   5
0000001
$ echo -n 5 | wc -m
1
```